# Looping over $ elements in bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

I am new to bison so this might sound trivial. I have a production suppose:

`A: B C D E { $$ = $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 }`

Now, is it possible to write a loop for $1 + $2 ... because I might have a large number of non terminals on the RHS and I don't want to manually write it down like this. I tried doing $i where i was a loop variable but that didn't work out.

Comment: In many grammars, the types of the terms is different (the type of `B` is different from the type of `C`), so there's no call to do what you're seeking to do.  I don't think there's a short-cut in standard Bison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. As far as `bison` is concerned, `$$`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. are identifiers, and they each have a type. So it would be like asking for a shortcut to a write var1 + var2 + var3... as a loop.